# Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors BUT atomic vector is FALSE

Tags: r, database, vector, package, atomic

I'm using the package rbacon to calibrate C14 dates for an age-depth model on a sediment core.

I am getting this error (I know it's a very common one):

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> is.recursive(c14)
[1] TRUE
> is.atomic(c14)
[1] FALSE
```

How can I have this error if it's not an atomic vector?
I tried changing my values to integers instead of floats, but no luck. Maybe something to do with the set function?

I attached my data table and code below if that helps.

```
#### data input ####
c14 <- read.table("dates_c14", header=TRUE)
c14 <- as.data.frame(t(c14))
c14
#          V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
# labID     A     B     C     D     E
# age    1550  2080  2680  3625  3940
# error    30    30    35    35    35
# depth  45.0  62.0  82.5 100.5 104.0


#### code ####
library(rbacon)
agedepth(set ="c14", BCAD = FALSE, unit = "cm", d.lab = "Depth (cm)",
         yr.lab ="cal BP", d.min = 1, d.max = 107, d.by = 1,
         depths = seq(0,1,length=107), depths.file = FALSE, yr.min =2016, yr.max = -3000,
         bins = c(), dark = set$dark, prob = 0.95, rounded = 1,
         d.res = 200, yr.res = 200, date.res = 100, grey.res = 100,
         rotate.axes = FALSE, rev.yr = FALSE, rev.d = FALSE, maxcalc = 500,
         height = 15, mirror = TRUE, up = TRUE, cutoff = 0.001,
         plot.range = TRUE, panels = layout(1), range.col = grey(0.5),
         range.lty = "12", mn.col = "red", mn.lty = "12", med.col = NA,
         med.lty = "12", C14.col = rgb(0, 0, 1, 0.35), C14.border = rgb(0, 0, 1,0.5), 
         cal.col = NA,cal.border = NA, hiatus.lty = "12", 
         greyscale = function(x) grey(1 - x), 
         normalise.dists = TRUE, cc=1, title ="Gulf of Aqaba Core",
         title.location = "topleft", after =1, bty = "l", 
         mar = c(3,3, 1, 1), 
         mgp = c(1.5, 0.7, 0), xaxs = "r", yaxs = "r", xaxt = "s",
         yaxt = "s", plot.pdf = TRUE, dates.only = FALSE, model.only = FALSE,
         cleanup = TRUE, talk = TRUE)
```

Comment: What if you don't but quotes around the `set=` parameter: `agedepth(set =c14, ...)`. But even then that looks like a very odd data.structure for `c14`. Those columns are probably all factors which is a mess. Are you sure that's how that function expects the data to be structured?

Comment: Thanks! But no quotes did not work either. I followed this structure for my date input: https://github.com/cran/rbacon/blob/master/inst/extdata/Cores/MSB2K/MSB2K.csv
(I tried .csv and .txt)